# Can I obtain a unitary block matrix from any invertible matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra, quantum-computation

Suppose A is any square invertible complex matrix.  Then
$$
C =
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
0 & A \\
\hline
A^{\dagger} & 0
\end{array}
\right]
$$
is a Hermitian matrix.

**My Question:**  Is there a way to do something similar to get a unitary matrix from A?  If necessary, suppose $detA = 1$.

Please let me know if it is not clear what I mean. The motivation comes from a quantum information theory question.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "get a unitary matrix from A"

Comment: Yes. See [**this question**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2853512/inverse-of-a-matrix-is-same-as-conjugate-transpose-of-matrix/2853595#2853595), which is closely related.

Comment: @StevenSagona I mean something perhaps like how I "got the Hermitian matrix C from A".  Essentially, I want to multiply a vector by the matrix A, but in quantum information theory, you only have unitary matrices to act on vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Let $H$ be any Hermitian matrix and $Id$ the identity matrix both of order $k$.

Thus, $Id\pm iH$ are invertible matrices. Define $U=(Id+iH)(Id-iH)^{-1}$.

Let $H=VDV^*$ be a spectral decomposition of $H$, i.e., $D$ is a real diagonal matrix and $V$ a unitary matrix.

Hence, $Id+iH=V(Id+iD)V^*$ and $(Id-iH)^{-1}=V(Id-iD)^{-1}V^*$. Thus, $U=V(Id+iD)(Id-iD)^{-1}V^*$.

Now you can easily check that $U$ is unitary, since its eigenvalues are $(1+i d_{ss})(1-i d_{ss})^{-1}$, $1\leq s\leq k$, (which have norm 1).

This idea comes from the Cayley parametrization (Check page 74 [here](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=SEcaDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA175&lpg=PA175&dq=a%20survey%20of%20matrix%20theory%20and%20matrix%20inequalities%20cayley%20parametrization&source=bl&ots=GxWUlaXbwU&sig=WfC4L18N5eODbmpXYh_sCh3fCx8&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjklP79s6ndAhUBNpAKHU5FAmsQ6AEwBHoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=a%20survey%20of%20matrix%20theory%20and%20matrix%20inequalities%20cayley%20parametrization&f=false)).

Now you can construct any Hermitian matrix $H$ from $A$ and use the formula $U=(Id+iH)(Id-iH)^{-1}$ to define a unitary matrix $U$.